# Incrementar valor en JS

Tags: html

hace un tiempito empece con JS, y ahora estoy viendo eventos.
Estoy intentando hacer un programa el cual cuando haga click en un boton el numero incremente en 1, pero no me estaria funcionando, les dejo el codigo.

```
    let contador = document.getElementById("counter");
let boton = document.getElementById("boton");

let numeroContador = 0;

function aumentarContador() {
    numeroContador++;
}

contador.textContent = numeroContador.toString();

boton.addEventListener("click", aumentarContador());
```

Esta de mas decir que las 2 etiquetas del html estan con sus respectivos ID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

suponiendo que tienes un input donde tienes el id `counter`. Deberias agregar el cambio en tu funcion `aumentarContador()`

```javascript
function aumentarContador(){
  numeroContador++;
  contador.value = numeroContador
}
```

en caso de que sea un span, h1, h2, hn:

```javascript
function aumentarContador(){
  numeroContador++;
  contador.innerHTML = numeroContador
}
```

Espero te sirva saludos.

Comment: El id counter, es un H1. Es el que va a mostrar los numeros

Comment: Con innerHTML funcionaria

Comment: Ya lo resolvi, al contador.textcontent lo tenia fuera de la funcion, por ende cuando se ejecute la funcion el contador no va a ser modificado. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda y tu tiempo de todas formas.